# apply media query in html code which is being bound by innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, angular

I need to add media query to a piece of HTML code which is being bound by innerHtml
For example -

```
<div class="end-timer-value" [innerHtml]="timerValue"></div>
```

and this timerValue gets returned from a service, something like -

```
str = `
            <div class="timer-outer-wrapper" style="display:flex">
              <div style="padding: 5px 16px;">Ends in: </div>
              <div class="hours-wrapper" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
                <div>${hoursLeft}</div>
                <div id="hours" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; letter-spacing: 0.01em; text-align: left; margin-top: -5px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;hrs</div>
              </div>
              <div style="padding: 5px 16px;">:</div>
              <div class="mins-wrapper" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
                <div>${minutesLeft}</div>
                <div id="minutes" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; letter-spacing: 0.01em; text-align: left; margin-top: -5px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;min</div>
              </div>
              <div style="padding: 5px 16px;">:</div>
              <div class="secs-wrapper" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
                <div>${remainingSeconds}</div>
                <div id="seconds" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; letter-spacing: 0.01em; text-align: left; margin-top: -5px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;sec</div>
              </div>
            </div>`;
    timerValue = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(str);
```

I have tried to add the following media query code in the main scss file but it doesn't work -

```
div.end-timer-value {
    div.timer-outer-wrapper {
        div.hours-wrapper {
            #hours {
                margin-left: 0px;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 1360px) {
                #hours {
                    margin-left: -6px;
                }
                #minutes {
                    margin-left: -5px;
                }
                #seconds {
                    margin-left: -5px;
                }
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 1190px) {
                #hours {
                    margin-left: -10px;
                }
                #minutes {
                    margin-left: -10px;
                }
                #seconds {
                    margin-left: -10px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, just an additional information, this is some sort of timer which is put under setInterval, so if you provide a solution, please keep that in mind, I hope that doesn't change anything related to media query working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [dangerously set innerhtml](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#dangerously-setting-the-inner-html) perchance? or is this not a react snippet? the angular and react tags are on here.

Answer (score 0):

that code does not look like Angular, but it is tagged with Angular. so i give an Angular solution:

What you need to do is create a template. that template can be loaded into the innerHTML with all css already applied.

something like this:

```
<div class="end-timer-value" [innerHtml]="templateRef"></div>

<ng-template #myTemplate>
  <div class="timer-outer-wrapper">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

ts file:

```
export class MyClass {
  @ViewChild('myTemplate') templateRef: TemplateRef<HTMLDivElement>;
}
```

as a short summary:

you define the styled HTML in the same component.html file as where you want to use it in innerHTML.
Then you create a reference with the help of @ViewChild. That reference can be thrown into the innerHTML.

as a bonus: you can even send that reference through a binding to a child component and render it there in an [innerHMLT]